# Rails Observer Alternatives for 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

With Observers officially [removed from Rails 4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers), I'm curious what other developers are using in their place. (Other than using the extracted gem.) While Observers were certainly abused and could easily become unwieldily at times, there were many use-cases outside of just cache-clearing where they were beneficial.

Take, for example, an application that needs to track changes to a model. An Observer could easily watch for changes on Model A and record those changes with Model B in the database. If you wanted to watch for changes across several models, then a single observer could handle that.

In Rails 4, I'm curious what strategies other developers are using in place of Observers to recreate that functionality.

Personally, I'm leaning towards a sort of "fat controller" implementation, where these changes are tracked in each models controller's create/update/delete method. While it bloats the behavior of each controller slightly, it does help in readability and understanding as all the code is in one place. The downside is that there's now code that is very similar scattered throughout several controllers. Extracting that code into helper methods is an option, but you're still left with calls to those methods littered everywhere. Not the end of the world, but not quite in the spirit of "skinny controllers" either.

ActiveRecord callbacks are another possible option, though one I don't personally like as it tends to couple two different models too closely together in my opinion.

So in the Rails 4, no-Observers world, if you had to create a new record after another record was created/updated/destroyed, what design pattern would you use? Fat controllers, ActiveRecord callbacks, or something else entirely?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm really surprised there aren't more answers posted for this question. Kind of disconcerting.

Comment: https://github.com/krisleech/wisper

Answer (score 88):

Take a look at [Concerns](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns)

Create a folder in your models directory called concerns. Add a module there:

```
module MyConcernModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save :do_something
  end

  def do_something
     ...
  end
end
```

Next, include that in the models you wish to run the after_save in:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyConcernModule
end
```

Depending on what you're doing, this might get you close without observers.

Comment: There are problems with this approach. Notably, It doesn't clean up your models; _include_ copies the methods from the module back in to your class. Extracting class methods out to a module may group them by concern, but the class is still just as bloated.

Comment: The title is 'Rails Observer Alternatives for 4.0' not 'How do I minimize bloat'.
How is it that concerns don't do the job Steven? And no, suggesting that 'bloat' is a reason why this won't work as a replacement for observers isn't good enough. You'll have to come up with a better suggestion to help the community or explain why concerns won't work as a replacement for observers. Hopefully you'll state both =D

Comment: Bloat is always a concern. A better alternative is [wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper), which, if implemented properly, allows you to clean up the concerns by extracting them out to separate classes that aren't tightly coupled to the models. This also makes it a lot easier to test in isolation

Comment: Model bloat or Whole App bloat by pulling in a Gem to do this - we can leave it up to individual preference. Thanks for the additional suggestion.

Comment: It would only bloat up IDE's method auto-complete menu, which should be fine for many people.

Answer (score 33):

They are in a [plugin](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) now.

Can I also recommend [an alternative](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper) which will give you controllers like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    @post.subscribe(PusherListener.new)
    @post.subscribe(ActivityListener.new)
    @post.subscribe(StatisticsListener.new)

    @post.on(:create_post_successful) { |post| redirect_to post }
    @post.on(:create_post_failed)     { |post| render :action => :new }

    @post.create
  end
end
```

Comment: How about ActiveSupport::Notifications?

Comment: @svoop `ActiveSupport::Notifications` are geared towards instrumentation, not generic sub/pub.

Comment: @Kris - you're right. It is used for instrumentation primarily, but I wonder what prevents it from being used as a generic method for pub/sub? it does provide the basic building blocks, right? In other words, what are the up/downsides to wisper compared to `ActiveSupport::Notifications`?

Comment: I've not used `Notifications` much but I'd say `Wisper` has a nicer API and features such as 'global subscribers', 'on prefix' and 'event mapping' which `Notifications` does not. A future release of `Wisper` will also allow async publishing via SideKiq/Resque/Celluloid. Also, potentially, in future Rails releases, the API for `Notifications` could change to be more instrumentation focused.

Answer (score 22):

My suggestion is to read James Golick's blog post at http://jamesgolick.com/2010/3/14/crazy-heretical-and-awesome-the-way-i-write-rails-apps.html (try to ignore how immodest the title sounds).

Back in the day it was all "fat model, skinny controller". Then the fat models became a giant headache, especially during testing. More recently the push has been for skinny models -- the idea being that each class should be handling one responsibility and a model's job is to persist your data to a database. So where does all my complex business logic end up? In business logic classes -- classes that represent transactions.

This approach can turn into a quagmire (giggity) when the logic starts getting complicated. The concept is sound though -- instead of triggering things implicitly with callbacks or observers that are hard to test and debug, trigger things explicitly in a class that layers logic on top of your model.

Comment: I've been doing something like this for a project over the last few months. You do end up with lots of little services, but the ease of testing and maintaining it definitely outweighs the disadvantages. My fairly extensive specs on this medium sized system still only take 5 seconds to run :)

Comment: Also known as PORO (Plain Old Ruby Objects), or service objects

Answer (score 13):

Using active record callbacks simply flips the dependency of your coupling. For instance, if you have `modelA` and a `CacheObserver` observing `modelA` rails 3 style, you can remove `CacheObserver` with no issue. Now, instead say `A` has to manually invoke the `CacheObserver` after save, which would be rails 4. You've simply moved your dependency so you can safely remove `A` but not `CacheObserver`.

Now, from my ivory tower I prefer the observer to be dependent on the model it's observing. Do I care enough to clutter up my controllers? For me, the answer is no.

Presumably you've put some thought into why you want/need the observer, and thus creating a model dependent upon its observer is not a terrible tragedy.

I also have a (reasonably grounded, I think) distaste for any sort of observer being dependent on a controller action. Suddenly you have to inject your observer in any controller action (or another model) that may update the model you want observed. If you can guarantee your app will only ever modify instances via create/update controller actions, more power to you, but that's not an assumption I would make about a rails application (consider nested forms, model business logic updating associations, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments @agmin. I'm happy to move away from using an Observer if there's a better design pattern out there. I'm most interested in how other people are structuring their code and dependancies to provide similar functionality (excluding caching). In my case, I'd like to record the changes to a model anytime its attributes are updated. I used to use an Observer to do that. Now I'm trying to decide between a fat controller, AR callback or something else I hadn't thought of. Neither seems elegant at the moment.

Answer (score 13):

[Wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper) is a great solution. My personal preference for callbacks is that they're fired by the models but the events are only listened to when a request comes in i.e. I don't want callbacks fired while I'm setting up models in tests etc. but I do want them fired whenever controllers are involved. This is really easy to setup with Wisper because you can tell it to only listen to events inside a block.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :register_event_listeners

  def register_event_listeners(&around_listener_block)
    Wisper.with_listeners(UserListener.new) do
      around_listener_block.call
    end
  end        
end

class User
  include Wisper::Publisher
  after_create{ |user| publish(:user_registered, user) }
end

class UserListener
  def user_registered(user)
    Analytics.track("user:registered", user.analytics)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

In some cases I simply use [Active Support Instrumentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html)

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument "my.custom.event", this: :data do
  # do your stuff here
end

ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "my.custom.event" do |*args|
  data = args.extract_options! # {:this=>:data}
end
```

Answer (score 4):

My alternative to Rails 3 Observers is a manual implementation which utilizes a callback defined within the model yet manages to (as agmin states in his answer above) "flip the dependency...coupling".

My objects inherit from a base class which provides for registering observers:

```
class Party411BaseModel

  self.abstract_class = true
  class_attribute :observers

  def self.add_observer(observer)
    observers << observer
    logger.debug("Observer #{observer.name} added to #{self.name}")
  end

  def notify_observers(obj, event_name, *args)
    observers && observers.each do |observer|
    if observer.respond_to?(event_name)
        begin
          observer.public_send(event_name, obj, *args)
        rescue Exception => e
          logger.error("Error notifying observer #{observer.name}")
          logger.error e.message
          logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
        end
    end
  end

end
```

(Granted, in the spirit of composition over inheritance, the above code could be placed in a module and mixed in each model.)

An initializer registers observers:

```
User.add_observer(NotificationSender)
User.add_observer(ProfilePictureCreator)
```

Each model can then define its own observable events, beyond the basic ActiveRecord callbacks.  For instance, my User model exposes 2 events:

```
class User < Party411BaseModel

  self.observers ||= []

  after_commit :notify_observers, :on => :create

  def signed_up_via_lunchwalla
    self.account_source == ACCOUNT_SOURCES['LunchWalla']
  end

  def notify_observers
    notify_observers(self, :new_user_created)
    notify_observers(self, :new_lunchwalla_user_created) if self.signed_up_via_lunchwalla
  end
end
```

Any observer that wishes to receive notifications for those events merely needs to (1) register with the model that exposes the event and (2) have a method whose name matches the event.  As one might expect, multiple observers can register for the same event, and (in reference to the 2nd paragraph of the original question) an observer can watch for events across several models.

The NotificationSender and ProfilePictureCreator observer classes below define methods for the events exposed by various models:

```
NotificationSender
  def new_user_created(user_id)
    ...
  end

  def new_invitation_created(invitation_id)
    ...
  end

  def new_event_created(event_id)
    ...
  end
end

class ProfilePictureCreator
  def new_lunchwalla_user_created(user_id)
    ...
  end

  def new_twitter_user_created(user_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

One caveat is that the names of all events exposed across all the models must be unique.

Answer (score 3):

I think the the issue with Observers being deprecated is not that observers were bad in and of themselves but that they were being abused.

I would caution against adding too much logic in your callbacks or simply moving code around to simulate the behavior of an observer when there is already a sound solution to this problem the Observer pattern.

If it makes sense to use observers then by all means use observers.  Just understand that you will need to make sure that your observer logic follows sound coding practices for example SOLID.

The observer gem is available on rubygems if you want to add it back to your project
https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

see this brief thread, while not full comprehensive discussion I think the basic argument is valid. 
https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

You could try https://github.com/TiagoCardoso1983/association_observers . It is not yet tested for rails 4 (which wasn't launched yet), and needs some more collaboration, but you can check if it does the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a PORO instead?

The logic behind this is that your 'extra actions on save' are likely going to be business logic. This I like to keep separate from both AR models (which should be as simple as possible) and controllers (which are bothersome to test properly)

```
class LoggedUpdater

  def self.save!(record)
    record.save!
    #log the change here
  end

end
```

And simply call it as such:

```
LoggedUpdater.save!(user)
```

You could even expand on it, by injecting extra post-save action objects

```
LoggedUpdater.save(user, [EmailLogger.new, MongoLogger.new])
```

And to give an example of the 'extras'. You might want to spiffy them up a bit though:

```
class EmailLogger
  def call(msg)
    #send email with msg
  end
end
```

If you like this approach, I recommend a read of [Bryan Helmkamps 7 Patterns](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) blog post.

EDIT: I should also mention that the above solution allows for adding transaction logic as well when needed. E.g. with ActiveRecord and a supported database:

```
class LoggedUpdater

  def self.save!([records])
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      records.each(&:save!)
      #log the changes here
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that [`Observable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) module from Ruby standard library cannot be used in active-record-like objects since instance methods `changed?` and `changed` will clash with the ones from [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5.2/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed).

[Bug report for Rails 2.3.2](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4056-rails-232-dirty-tracking-has-error-when-observable-is-included)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same probjem! I find a solution ActiveModel::Dirty so you can track your model changes!

```
include ActiveModel::Dirty
before_save :notify_categories if :data_changed? 


def notify_categories
  self.categories.map!{|c| c.update_results(self.data)}
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html