# Independent observation of model events in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way in rails to implement the situation where when Model A is created, Model B can observe this and change.

One solution is some kind of filter such as an after_create in Model A.  However having some Model B code in Model A seems like a bad practise.

Another solution is to have some code in Model B's controller to handle this which also seems like a bad idea.

Ideally Model B or some kind of independent observer class should be able to observe the creation of all Model A's and then act as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to OP for pointing out that this was for Rails4 as the question was originally tagged which I had missed to notice.  [Rails 4 alternative to Observers question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165260/rails-observer-alternatives-for-4-0) here at SO has several great answers.

**Original Answer:**

This can be done using [`Observer`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer).  Say you want a `ModelAObserver`, where you'd define the operations required on `ModelB`, you can create a new file `app/models/model_a_observer.rb` manually or use the generator `rails g observer ModelA`.

Then define the required callbacks in the `ModelAObserver`:

```
# app/models/model_a_observer.rb
class ModelAObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   observe :model_a

   def after_create(new_model_a_record)
     ...
     # Operations on ModelB
     ...
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you that help me.  I'm using rails 4 in which observers have been deprecated, but your answer led me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165260/rails-observer-alternatives-for-4-0

Comment: @user3091013, thanks for the link.  I've added a short note at the top of this answer with the link you posted.