# group creator transfered to other user if group creator leaves group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, user-accounts

**First question**: I have a group model that `belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"` and if the creator leaves I want someone else in the group to become the "creator". How would I do this?

As a **second question**, I would also like to give the leaving creator to choose a new creator when leaving, or let it be automatically assigned.

as of right now these are what my models look like:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"

  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
  has_many :memberships, :foreign_key => "new_group_id"
```

and my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :groups, foreign_key: :creator_id

  has_many :memberships, foreign_key: :member_id
  has_many :new_groups, through: :memberships
```

As a **third question**, I would like the group to be destroyed when the creator leaves. How can I set up this kind of relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are 3 questions, and the first two are quite open, so I'd try to answer all of them in order making some assumptions down the road.

**First question**

This depends on what do you want the behavior for choosing a new *creator* to be. Do you want it to be automatically assigned from the current `members`? Do you want to give other members to have the change to auto-assign themselves as *creator*? In the latter you need to provide your members a full UI (routes, controllers, views) for that purpose, so I'll show you how would I code the first option.

First, I'd encapsulate the *group leaving* logic into its own method on the `Group` model, that we'll use in the controller for this purpose. On `Group` we define the logic for assigning as new `creator`. The logic here will be to pass the method a `new_creator` if we have it, or default to the first of the `members` if not given.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reassign(new_creator = nil)
    new_creator ||= members.first

    if new_creator
      self.creator = new_creator
      save
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

As an alternative approach, you can move this logic into an [`Observer`](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) (or [any alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165260/rails-observer-alternatives-for-4-0)) that will observe on `Group` model for the attribute `creator_id` to be nulled.

**Second question**

This one will involve a full UI that you'll need to figure out yourself according to your specifications. In short, I'd create a new action in your `GroupsController` for `members` to leave groups like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :groups do
  member do 
    get :leave
    patch :reassign
  end
end

# app/controllers/groups_controller.rb
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def leave
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end

  def reassign
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    if @group.reassign(params[:new_creator_id])
      redirect_to my_fancy_path
    else
      render :leave
    end 
  end
end
```

In your views you'll have your `form_for @group` with the new member candidates (possible with a `select_tag :new_creator_id`) and the rest of your UI as you prefer.

**Third question**

This is the easiest. You just define your association like this and you'll get all `User` groups destroyed after the user is deleted.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, foreign_key: :creator_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: You answered my questions perfectly. very clear and easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: Happy to know! Just let me know if you can fit the code into your app. And don't forget to upvote / accept and so on ! ;)