# Is it possible to use callback conditionals in an observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model callback like this:

```
after_save :foobar, except: :create
```

The code this runs is mostly irrelevant to the model itself, so I wish to move it into an observer. I find I can do something like this:

```
def after_save(model)
  foobar(model)
end
```

However, this does not maintain the `except: :create` behavior of my callback, which is very important in this instance.

Is it possible to use callback conditionals such as `except` in a Rails observer? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: You're going to have do define what you mean by "Rails observer" as it was removed from the core in Rails 4. Are you talking about the Rails::Observers gem?

Comment: @max Yes, I'm talking about the now-gem previously part of rails core.

Comment: Is this legacy code or why  do you think observers are a good answer to your given problem?

Comment: @max I believe observers are a good answer to my problem because the code in question is updating attributes of many records and should be run after certain records are saved. As I said in the question, currently I have this written as a callback in the model, which seems wrong to me because the code doesn't actually do anything with the "current" record it runs in, hence my desire to switch the code to an observer.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like kneejerk contrarianism, but there is a reason why they fell by the wayside and other alternatives like service objects that do the job better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165260/rails-observer-alternatives-for-4-0

Comment: @max Are those reasons relevant to my question here? Do you have information for why abandoning the gem I'm already using would be the best path to solve this problem?

Comment: Its up to you to decide if its relevant to the particular question here but it definely ties in. Observers just like model callbacks are implicit instead of expliclit like calls to service objects. While it may intially seem like a convenient solution it becomes increasingly complex to handle when and where your callbacks/observers are fired as the complexity of your application grows. But of course do as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define

```rb
after_save :foobar, except: :create
```

it means that you only trigger the callback for update, so just define in your  observer:

```rb
def after_update(model)
  # do something here
end
```

Comment: Excellent, that is precisely what I was looking for. I hadn't made the connection between when my callback was actually running and other lifecycle events that might correspond to. Thank you!